# MSMQ sending message problem... (c#)

Tags: c#, msmq

My code :

```
  string _path = "mymachine\\Private$\\example";
  // create a message queue object
  MessageQueue MQueue = new MessageQueue(_path);

  // create the message and set the base properties
  Message Msg = new Message("Messagem");
  Msg.ResponseQueue = MQueue;
  Msg.Priority = MessagePriority.Normal;
  Msg.UseJournalQueue = true;
  Msg.Label = "gps1";      

  // send the message
  MQueue.Send(Msg);

  // close the mesage queue
  MQueue.Close();
```

No error, but nothing in my MessageQueue...
Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem...
My MessageQueue was created with transaction true...

Comment: That is an annoying issue with MSMQ (or the .NET wrapper, I'm not sure where the issue comes in).

Comment: Correct. You need to replace the last two methods with.. MQueue.Send(Msg, transaction); transaction.Commit(); MQueue.Close(); .. Otherwise, when you create the new Queue, turn transactions off -> New MessageQueue(_path, false);